# Find an element with a period in it's name

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<T24.MESSAGE>
<TRANSACTION.TYPE>CHEQUE.ON.THEM.AUTH</TRANSACTION.TYPE>
<TRANSACTION.ID>FT14273PKQ14</TRANSACTION.ID>
</T24.MESSAGE>
```

I am trying to find the `TRANSACTION.TYPE` element, using the xpath query `/TRANSACTION.TYPE`. However, this is returning nothing, and I think it is because the element has a period in the name.

Is there a way to escape the period? Though according to the MS reference it isn't needed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Edit: I have also tried `/T24.MESSAGE/TRANSACTION.TYPE` and just `TRANSACTION.TYPE` and neither work.

Code I use to read it:

```
byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
{
   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, xmlReaderSettings));
   var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
   var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("/TRANSACTION.TYPE"); //null
   //...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to read the nodes?

Comment: Does your XML have namespaces in it? I've had trouble using xpath on XML with namespaces.

Comment: Do you need the Xpath `/T24.MESSAGE/TRANSACTION.TYPE` rather than `/TRANSACTION.TYPE`?

Comment: @HansKilian Yes we do have namespaces, I took them out for the example. Is extra work needed if there's a namespace associated?

Comment: @petelids I'm not sure, I figured just `/TRANSACTION.TYPE` would work because `T24.MESSAGE` is my root. I have tried both though and neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using namespaces you might try using a namespace agnostic form in your code. It'd look like this

```
    var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='TRANSACTION.TYPE']");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your namespace. You'll need to create a [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass that to your `SelectSingleNode` call.

In the below I've created a namespace of `urn:test`:

```
string strXML = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
            <T24.MESSAGE xmlns=""urn:Test"">
            <TRANSACTION.TYPE>CHEQUE.ON.THEM.AUTH</TRANSACTION.TYPE>
            <TRANSACTION.ID>FT14273PKQ14</TRANSACTION.ID>
            </T24.MESSAGE>";

byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
{
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream));
    var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

    XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);

    //Add the namespaces used. In this instance I'm setting a prefix of "t"
    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("t", "urn:Test");

    //pass the XmlNamespaceManager to the call to SelectSingleNode
    //the XPath also includes the root element
    var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//t:T24.MESSAGE/t:TRANSACTION.TYPE", xmlnsManager);

    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

}
```

This code correctly ouptuts

> TRANSACTION.TYPE

Answer (score 0):

This certainly works

```
string yourXMLString = @"<T24.MESSAGE>
                         <TRANSACTION.TYPE>CHEQUE.ON.THEM.AUTH</TRANSACTION.TYPE>
                         <TRANSACTION.ID>FT14273PKQ14</TRANSACTION.ID>
                         </T24.MESSAGE>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXMLString);

var res = xDoc.Descendants("T24.MESSAGE")
              .Elements("TRANSACTION.TYPE");
```

result: `<TRANSACTION.TYPE>CHEQUE.ON.THEM.AUTH</TRANSACTION.TYPE>`

Comment: Let me try this quick.

Comment: This didn't work for me. `xDoc.Descendants("T24.MESSAGE")` has no elements.

Comment: .Net fiddle here - [https://dotnetfiddle.net/2bXOg9](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2bXOg9). Your source XML might contain some namespaces - that could be why it is not working.

Comment: You can include your name space in your query, e.g. `xDoc.Descendants("{foo.com}T24.MESSAGE").Elements("{bar.com}TRANSACTION.TYPE");`