# How do I find this xpath node? One of the elements has periods, and one of the elements doesn't have a key

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm a bit of a XML/PowerShell noob, so forgive any incorrect term usage.

Here is the XML I'm attempting to manipulate:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" >
            <section name="DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="DBConString" serializeAs="String">
                <value></value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ScriptPath" serializeAs="String">
              <value></value>
            </setting>
        </DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Throughout this project, I've been able to use powershell to modify similar configs (using Azure DevOps). I do that with this general format(unrelated to above config):

```
    $node=$xml.SelectNodes("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='SMTPUSER']")
    $node.SetAttribute("value", "$(SMTPUSER)")
```

However, because of the placement of `value`, I can't get this to work (related to above config):

```
$node=$xml.SelectNodes("configuration/userSettings/DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='ScriptPath']")
$node.value="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted/DBScripts/artefacts_Risk/"
```

I found this link : [Finding Elements with Period in Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000350/find-an-element-with-a-period-in-its-name) which helped me create this:

```
$node=$xml.SelectNodes("//configuration/userSettings/*[local-name()='DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings']/setting[@name='ScriptPath']")
    $node.value="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted/DBScripts/artefacts_Risk/"
```

I understand that the way I have value being selected is different in the two examples, but I've tried it both ways for the first script, and same error.

Both versions ending up failing on:
`The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.`

The full error is:

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\azagent\A4\_work\_temp\500556f4-6c37-4021-972b-f665fa907911.ps1:16 char:1
+ $node.value="data source=ipaddress;initial catalog=dbname_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
 
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

In case it's important, here is the full powershell script for this task:

```
- powershell: |
    dir
    Write-Host "Verify DB Connection String is Accurate"
    if("$(EzAcquireConStr)" -like '*risk*') {
          # Write-Host 'Your string contains the word world'
    } else {
          Write-Host 'Default Connection string does not contain word risk, failing pipeline'
          exit 1
    }
    Write-Host "Manipulate Config to match repo's DBScripts"
    $xmlFileName = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DatabaseUpdate/DatabaseUpdate.exe.config"
    $xml=New-Object XML
    $xml.Load($xmlFileName)
    $node=$xml.SelectNodes("configuration/userSettings/*[local-name()='DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings']/setting[@name='DBConString']")
    $node.value="$(EzAcquireConStr)"
    $node=$xml.SelectNodes("configuration/userSettings/*[local-name()='DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings']/setting[@name='ScriptPath']")
    $node.value="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted/DBScripts/app/"
    $xml.Save($xmlFileName)
    Write-Host "Run DB Update Using above criteria"
    & $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DatabaseUpdate/DatabaseUpdate.exe
    Write-Host "If DB Update Errors, fail pipeline"
    if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) {
      exit $LASTEXITCODE
    }
  displayName: 'Inject DBScripts Path for Tool'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$node=$xml.SelectNodes("configuration/userSettings/DatabaseUpdate.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='ScriptPath']")`

This doesn't return a single XML node as you seem to expect based on naming of the variable. Instead, it returns an instance of `XPathNodeList`, whose base class is [`XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist?view=net-5.0).

You can use its [`Item()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist.item?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlNodeList_Item_System_Int32_) method to access individual XML nodes of the result by index:

```
$node.Item(0).Value = '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted/DBScripts/artefacts_Risk/'
```

---

How do I know this? I just entered this in the console, which gave me the typename and base class:

```
$node.GetType()
```